# What if an abbreviation is at the end of a declarative sentence? Should I duplicate a full stop sign?

Tags: punctuation

What if an abbreviation is at the end of a declarative sentence? Should I duplicate a full stop sign? If the following sentence begins with a proper noun, not putting two periods may be confusing, in theory.

Edit: It used to be 'contraction' instead of 'abbreviation'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't duplicate the full stop, even if it is potentially confusing.  If necessary and possible, rephrase to avoid the issue, either by expanding the abbreviation, or by using a synonym, or re-ordering the words.

However, it is rarely confusing as there are other grammatical indicators of the end of a sentence.  It is usually possible to insert full stops in a paragraph which has no punctuation (and this is sometimes done as an exercise for learners)

Here are some examples of rephrasing

> Peter bought eggs, cheese, etc. John bought the wine.  (has abbreviation point acting as full stop, but there is little chance of confusion.)

> Peter bought eggs, cheese, et cetera. John bought the wine (expand abbreviation)

> Peter bought eggs, cheese and so on. John bought the wine. (synonym)

> Eggs, cheese, etc. were bought by Peter.  John bought the wine. (reorder, using the passive)

> John bought the wine. Peter bought eggs, cheese, etc.  (reorder paragraph)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean an abbreviation and not a contraction. An contraction does not have a period. It has an apostrophe to indicate where letters have been omitted.

For example, "don't" is a contraction for "do not". We don't write a period after "don't". The apostrophe shows that it's a contraction.

"Mr." is an abbreviation for "mister". It has a period.

But to answer your question: No, the convention is that if a sentence ends with an abbreviation, we just put one period. Could this create ambiguity? Possibly. A sentence must begin with a capital letter, so that would signal to the reader that this is a new sentence even without the period. It could happen that you have a word that would be capitalized even if it was in the middle of a sentence, like a person's name, so that it could be ambiguous or confusing. Fortunately this happens rarely enough that it's just not a big deal.